# Why are some characters being added when I paste URL link in Git?

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

Okay Git beginner here.

- I've opened the Git Bash inside my folder.
- I've been trying to set the remote origin, and after I type the command, for example: **git remote add origin**,  *I would like to paste a link*

https://bitbucket.org/ExampleName/demo/src/master/ - the link

And when I paste, using the **right click -> paste**, I get the following link

^[[200~hhttps://bitbucket.org/aca5/demo/src/master/∼

With **^[[200~h** *before*, and **∼** *after* the link. Why does this happen?

Note: crtl + v does not seem to work, same as ctrl + shift + v

Note2: Using Windows machine

Comment: Use control-shift-v to paste in a terminal

Comment: Okay, I will. Thanks for the advice, but I'd still want to know what's going on with right click + paste

Comment: Did you do that in `cmd` or `git bash`? Probably `git bash` since there `Crtl`-`v` do not work. Anyway in bitbucket page there is a button "clone" to copy correct remote address. You are coping wrong value! Is should be something like: `https://bitbucket.com/scm/demo/src.git`.

Comment: @MarekR Yeah, it's git bash. **shift + insert** does the job. But the same link pasted with **right click -> paste** just adds those characters.

Comment: You are coping wrong thing! See update in my comment!

Comment: This is not a Git thing and not a bash thing; it's a terminal-emulator thing. Some terminal emulators like to insert extra stuff before and after the pasted text. Find these in your terminal emulator's settings; if necessary, turn the feature off where it doesn't work (such as perhaps in git-bash).

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the *~/inputrc* file to include the following directive:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste Off
```

Comment: Should be '~/.inputrc' (with a dot at the beginning, no?